# Git escribe código en mi código y este no funciona

Tags: git, github

Uso el entorno de visual studio code para desarrollar y tire los siguientes comandos:

```
git add . -f
git commit -m "Primer guardado en git"
git push origin main
```

después de eso me dio un fallo de rsf o algo así la cosa es que me di cuenta que dese el propio entorno podía hacer lo mismo pero de forma grafica y así lo hice me subió el proyecto de laravel sin ningun problema, no le eche cuentas a revisar que el código estaba bien y hoy me he puesto a trabajar en el y me encuentro con esta joyita:

```
 syntax error, unexpected token "<<", expecting ")"

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\etiquestas\bootstrap\cache\routes-v7.php:44
     40▕         1 =>
     41▕         array (
     42▕           0 =>
     43▕           array (
  ➜  44▕ <<<<<<< HEAD
     45▕             '_route' => 'generated::buQapnFHfX9VWn9m',
     46▕ =======
     47▕             '_route' => 'generated::levisqGoa6M2BE0X',
     48▕ >>>>>>> 65ef07d9 (boostrap y tailwing, entorno amigable)
"grep" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

¿ Como puedo limpiar el código en este fichero y en todos los demás  ?

Git status:

```
 git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   storage/logs/laravel.log

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Comment: Esos son marcadores de conflicto. Hiciste un merge o un rebase / cherry-pick / revert? Si te aparecieron conflictos, debiste resolverlos de forma apropiada (y tal parece que no es el caso).

Comment: Entonces tengo que ir archivo por archivo revisando si hay el código este de conflicto y dando aceptar o algo así ?

Comment: es un proyecto de laravel que seguramente tenga mas archivos de los que pueda contar

Comment: Ehhhh..... podría ser necesario saber si tienes marcadores de ese tipo.... pero no lo tienes que hacer abriendo archivo por archivo. Puedes usar grep para que busque por ti. Algo como `git grep -n '<<<<<<'`

Comment: Cual es la salida de `git status`? De pronto eso nos podría indicar en qué andas.

Comment: No lo pongas como comentario. Edita la pregunta y ponlo ahí.

Comment: @eftshift0 oks lo quito de aqui y lo pongo arriba

Comment: Ok.... no se ve que estes en medio de un conflicto.... _asumo_ que hubo un conflicto antes, no se resolvió apropiadamente, se agregaron los archivos con los conflictos todavía en el código y se hizo `git commit` (la definición de un **no-go**). En realidad no sabemos por tu descripción _por qué_ hubo un conflicto (no se habla de rebase/merge/cherry-pick/revert, que serían los causantes naturales de conflictos). Si lo que quieres es salir pronto del paso, busca los conflictos (con `git grep -n '<<<<<' como había dicho antes) y resuélvelos apropiadamente de tal forma que el código te funcione.

Comment: Lo otro que podrías hacer es _analizar_ de donde salieron los conflictos y entonces tratar de acomodar la revisión en la que fueron introducidos y arreglarla (bien enmendándola o haciendo la operación que lo causó de nuevo)..... claro, esto implica reescribir la historia lo que puede tener consecuencias que salen del _scope_ de la pregunta original.

Comment: Como va la corección?

Comment: @eftshift0 pues mal por que me ha puesto conflictos en las librerias de bootstrap y demas, veo que es perder el tiempo es mejor coger un proyecto limpio y añadirle lo principal. Cepillarme el repositorio y crearlo de nuevo con el contenido corregido que corregir este.

Comment: @eftshift0 me puedes recomendar alguna guía de github para que esto no me vuelva a pasar ?

Comment: En tu descripción del problema, no queda claro _el origen_ del problema (o sea, qué operaciones hiciste que hicieron que los conflictos aparecieran) así que no te puedo dar recomendaciones desde el punto de vista del _flujo de trabajo_. Lo que sí es obvio es que hubo conflictos que no fueron atendidos de la forma apropiada así que en ese sentido: cuando aparezcan conflictos (cosa que es frecuente), resuélvelos de la forma apropiada.

Comment: @eftshift0 no tengo mucha experiencia en git el guardado lo hice hace días por eso te he preguntado si me podrías recomendar alguna guía para que esto no me vuelva a pasar

Comment: Ah ah.... en realidad, no sabría qué recomendarte... lo que yo leí para poder entender muchos de los conceptos de git fue https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2

Comment: @eftshift0 bueno por algo se empieza, gracias !!

Comment: espero no sea muy tarde, pon la salida de correr el comando `git reflog` para darnos idea de los ultimos comandos que ejecutaste

Comment: @RuslanLópez Pues si es un poco tarde, pero aun así gracias por la ayuda, cogí los archivos importantes de laravel y lo migre a un proyecto nuevo y empecé de nuevo por así decirlo. creo que será mejor que cierre la pregunta